# How to embed latex in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I want to be able to output nicely formatted math code. So I decided to learn latex and maxima (and use all that in org-mode).

That's when I came across this tutorial http://maxima.sourceforge.net/contrib/maxiplot/maxiplot_en.pdf.

And there, I found this program in section 3.2.1:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[amsmath]{maxiplot}
\[   %Math mode begin
\begin{maxima}
f: x/(x^3-3*x+2),     /* Integrating it */
tex('integrate(f,x)), /* will show its integral... */
print("="),
tex(integrate(f,x)),  /* ...and the result */
print("+K")
\end{maxima}
\]   %Math mode end
```

I tried to execute it, in an org-buffer, by pressing `C-c C-x \`. But I see no results. The polynomial `f: x/(x^3-3*x+2)` gets pretty-printed and that's all. But there's not output like anything in the PDF file; a nice integral and so on.

I tried `C-c C-x C-l` too and the image is blank.

Can anyone tell me, how do I show the output of this latex/maxima program in the org-buffer?

Comment: I think Org only renders simple LaTeX inline. If this is correct, then for complicated LaTeX fragments that depend on external packages, you need to export to LaTeX and then compile to PDF.

Comment: I guess you're trying to actually execute the code, so LaTeX must be able to run maxima. Try exporting to pdf and running pdflatex manually with `--shell-escape` option (it might be named `--enable-write18` or something like that). An alternative way might be to put maxima code as a maxima babel block instead, I think (but not sure...) you can ask org to use the result in the latex export.

Comment: Here's how I embed Maxima code in Org: https://github.com/wvxvw/uni-infinitesimal-calculus/blob/316cdd4ae7ea86e03921eb6e6c7df29a70408525/assignment-14.org (my calculus assignment...) you'd also need this patch: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12402/why-is-org-adding-a-label-in-custom-babel-environment/12408#12408

Answer (score 8):

`\usepackage` commands go in the latex preamble, not the document body. You can add these commands with:

```
#+LATEX_HEADER_EXTRA: \usepackage...
```

Then you would add your LaTeX code inside of:

```
#+BEGIN_LATEX
\begin{maxima}
f: x/(x^3-3*x+2),     /* Integrating it */
tex('integrate(f,x)), /* will show its integral... */
print("="),
tex(integrate(f,x)),  /* ...and the result */
print("+K")
\end{maxima}
#+END_LATEX
```

blocks.

The above would only work when exported to PDF, not in Emacs buffers.

EDIT: In more recent versions of Org mode (Org mode 9.0 or later) the syntax for export blocks has been changed: instead of `#+BEGIN_LATEX ... #+END_LATEX`, you now have to say `#+BEGIN_EXPORT latex ... #+END_EXPORT`. See https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs/org-mode.git/tree/etc/ORG-NEWS#n2665 - although note that the line number is going to be obsolete as soon as the next release appears: it might be safer to search for `BEGIN_EXPORT` on that page instead. Alternatively, you can (and should) take a look at the `ORG-NEWS` file that is locally available, probably under `/usr/share/emacs` or `/usr/local/share/emacs`, assuming you use the Org mode that is distributed with Emacs. If you install your own, you presumably know where and can therefore find the `etc/ORG-NEWS` file whereever you installed Org mode.

Comment: `#+BEGIN_LATEX` produced `\begin{latex}` in the `.tex`-file (org 9.0). Maybe that's a new change due to [the new treatment of special blocks](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/org-special-blocks.html). Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: seems like it's fixable using `#+BEGIN_EXPORT latex`, which is the standard completion for `<l`<kbd>Tab</kbd> (that is an ell).